# Multiple inheritance and default values in C++

Tags: inheritance, c++-cli

I'd like to use multiple inheritance to create a set of default values at the object instantiation.

The concept is very simple and it is based on order of parent classes in the child class definition. During the instantiation I was hoping that child will finish with the default values of LAST parent class used in the definition of the child class.

Now I know that my assumption was not right as the output result is different then expected. C++ compiler returns an C2385 error saying: *ambiguous access of 'member'.*

**Question:**

1. is there any chance I can say to compiler to behave as I expect or
2. if not, is there any other 'easy' chance to do this?

In my concept I wanter to use automated dispatch to generate a object with a set of default values. I was hoping C++ compiler to resolve the conflict on its own as it does it when during the instantiation when the child class has one parent class only.

In the code below I expect `ch` values to be `n1=3, o1=5` when Child class is defined like that: `class Child : public Mother, public Father` and `ch` values to be `n1=1, o1=1` when Cild class is defined like that: `class Child : public Father, public Mother`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace System;

class Mother
{
    public: int n1=1;
    public: int o1=1;
};

class Father
{
    public: int n1 = 3;
    public: int o1 = 5;
};

class Child : public Mother, public Father
{
    //public: int n1 = 2;
    //public: int o1 = 4;
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
Mother mt = Mother();
Father ft = Father();
Child ch = Child();

Console::WriteLine(L"Mother n1: " + mt.n1);
Console::WriteLine(L"Mother o1: " + mt.o1);
Console::WriteLine(L"Father n1: " + ft.n1);
Console::WriteLine(L"Father o1: " + ft.o1);
Console::WriteLine(L"Child n1: " + ch.n1);
Console::WriteLine(L"Child o1: " + ch.o1);
Console::ReadKey();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you to learn C# and use it for .Net projects. C++ is very good but not in its C++.Net dialect. It is form of perversion.

Comment: It look like CLI not C++.

Comment: Is it `CLI`? Or `C#`? I cannot tell.

Comment: it is C++ in .net environment

Comment: @nwp It's C++/CLI but the question is about a pure C++ feature (multiple inheritance) and barely uses CLI types, so I'm adding the C++ tag back in while keeping the C++/CLI one.

Answer (score 3):

The rule for member lookup for a name in a class is basically: either the class has that name (in which case lookup stops), or exactly one of its base classes has that name. If multiple base classes have the same name, lookup fails as being ambiguous.

In this case, `Child` has no member named `n1` but it has *two* base classes that do (`Mother` and `Father`) - so that's ambiguous as to which `n1` you mean.

> In the code below I expect ch values to be `n1=3`, `o1=5`

The order of base classes here is irrelevant. If you want that to happen, you need to be explicit about which values you're bringing in:

```
class Child : public Mother, public Father
{
    using Father::n1;
    using Father::o1;
};
```

*Now* lookup will find `n1` and `o1` in `Child` and they will be 3 and 5, respectively.

Comment: OK understood. I've knew this already. But is there any chance that I can, for example, set a compiler option or a compiler directive which cause that only last defined parent class mambers and their default values will take presidence over any potentially conflicting definitions? What I'm looking for is it any chance to achieve this type inheritance in IMPLICIT rather than EXPLICIT (`using Father::n1`) way. Is it possible?

Comment: and what about others languages? Do you think is it possible in different environments?

Comment: @user1146081 There are a LOT of languages. I'm sure it's possible in one of 'em...

Answer (score 0):

You should probably stop redeclaring the same variable names and thereby making ambiguous - or useless - the previously declared ones. I don't know how other languages do it, but C++ is not them.

If you want 'default' values, just inherit the *same* member variables but give them different values via the constructors. The derived classes can call the base constructor(s) in order to pass their own values back during construction.

```
struct Base
{
    int m_number;

    Base(int n): m_number{n} {} // parameterised ctor for Derived, etc.
    Base(): m_number{42} {} // default ctor
};

struct Derived
{
    Derived(): Base{64} {} // override Base default value
};

Base myBase{}; // m_number == 42
Derived myDerived{}; // m_number == 64
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that it does not work as you expected (and some of the answers explain why) I would question your design decision to use inheritance for the scenario you describe.

Instead you could use something along the lines of:

```
Interface IValueProvider
{
  int Value1 { get; }
  int Value2 { get; }
}

class Mother : IValueProvider
{
    private: int n1=1;
    private: int o1=1;

    int Value1 { get {return n1;}; }
    int Value2 { get {return n2;}; }
};

// Implement Father similarly to Mother

class Child : IValueProvider
{
    private: List<IValueProvider> valueProviders;

    // Provide a mechanism to populate valueProviders, likely during construction.

    int Value1 { 
       get {
          return valueProviders.Last( v => v.Value1 );
       }; 
    }

    int Value2 { 
       get {
          return valueProviders.Last( v => v.Value2 );
       }; 
    }
};
```

Now you can control the values the child returns by ordering the items in the valueProviders list held in the child. You could also enhance it so that if a value is not set, it will take the previous item in the list and return that value.

For brevity I have used C# like notation, but you can achieve this in C++. Use and abstract class instead of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

`ch` here doesn't have single `o1` and `n1`, hence it is saying ambiguous access, it has subobjects of `Mother` and `Father`. And since you are using it directly

```
Console::WriteLine(L"Child n1: " + ch.n1);
Console::WriteLine(L"Child o1: " + ch.o1);
```

Compiler cannot decide which `n1` and `o1`to access.

You can acess it using class names, like this

```
cout << "Child n1: " + ch.Father::n1;
```

One Suggestion, Please avoid using Same variable names. Happy Coding.